# Is this matrix defined from an integral of a non-negative function positive definite?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I have a function $f(x)$ defined as

\begin{equation}
f(x) := \sum_{n = 1}^N c_n f_n(x) = \mathbf{f}(x)^T \mathbf{c},
\end{equation}

where

\begin{align}
\mathbf{f}(x) := \begin{bmatrix} f_1(x) \\ f_2(x) \\ \vdots \\ f_N(x) \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{c} := \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_N \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Think of the $f_n(x)$ as polynomials and $c_n \in \mathbb{R}$. I am interested in the following integral over some domain $D$:

\begin{equation}
\int_D f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}

Substituting the definition of $f(x)$ and simplifying a bit, we get

\begin{align}
\int_D f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_D (\mathbf{f}(x)^T \mathbf{c})^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_D (\mathbf{f}(x)^T \mathbf{c}) (\mathbf{f}(x)^T \mathbf{c}) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_D \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{f}(x) \mathbf{f}(x)^T \mathbf{c} \, \mathrm{d}x  \quad \text{(transpose of scalar)} \\
&= \mathbf{c}^T \int_D \mathbf{f}(x) \mathbf{f}(x)^T  \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathbf{c} \\
\end{align}

Let us define the matrix $F := \int_D \mathbf{f}(x) \mathbf{f}(x)^T  \, \mathrm{d}x$. Notice that $F$ is square and symmetric. We finally obtain

\begin{equation}
\int_D f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \mathbf{c}^T \, F \, \mathbf{c}.
\end{equation}

> I believe that the last equality proves that the matrix $F$ is positive definite, but Matlab disagrees with me. Is my reasoning correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't it be semi-positive definite?

Comment: In other words, there are certainly choices of the polynomials $f_k(x)$ that would make the matrix $F$ singular.

Comment: Is it positive definite if $f(x)$ is only $0$ if all $c_n$ are $0$ and all $f_n(x)$ are just linear polynomials?